# Parse attribute of Media Element

Tags: c#-4.0, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml, windows-phone

I want to parse url attribute from the XML and show image in image control (the one reffered to by the URL) in listbox from the following feed link: http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml

My code is:

```
var ComingNewsFromUri = from rss in XElement.Parse(e.Result).Descendants("item")
                        select new  NewsItems
                        {
                            Title = rss.Element("title").Value,
                            PubDate = rss.Element("pubDate").Value,
                            Description = rss.Element("description").Value
                        };
```

Answer (score 0):

For RSS, I would recommend using SyndicationFeed and SyndicationItem....does all the parsing and converting to objects automatically and brilliantly for you.

http://ryanhayes.net/blog/how-to-build-an-rss-feed-reader-in-windows-phone-7part-i-retrieving-parsing-and-displaying-post-titles/

I have an RSS feed app on the store myself using SyndicationFeed and it is very reliable and convenient.

Here is another sample by Microsoft

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/RSS-Reader-Sample-1702775f